# Jquery Menu UL LI insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am bound by a menu embed in a CMS (dont have source code), so this is what the menu looks like

```
 <li class="dir dgn-root    Item-2">
   <a href="#" title=""><span>Menu1</span></a><div class="mega_submenu Column2 Column3" style="display: none;">
 <ul class="mega_submenu_ul">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li class="   first-item SunItem-1">
         <a href="#" title="Templates">
            <span>Templates</span>
         </a>
        </li>
       <li class="   SunItem-2">
          <a href="#" title="Questions and Answers">
            <span>Questions and Answers</span>
          </a>
       </li>
       <li class="   SunItem-3">
             <a href="#" title="Template Package">
               <span>Template Package</span>
             </a>
       </li>
        <li class="   SunItem-4">
             <a href="#" title="Silver Package">
              <span>Silver Package</span>
             </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     <ul>
       <li class="   SunItem-5">
             <a href="#" title="Gold Package">
                <span>Gold Package</span>
             </a>
       </li>
       <li class="   SunItem-6">
             <a href="#" title="Platinum Package">
                 <span>Platinum Package</span>
             </a>
       </li>
       <li class="   SunItem-7">
            <a href="#" title="Features">
                 <span>Features</span>
           </a> 
       </li>
       <li class="   last-item SunItem-8">
            <a href="#" title="Portfolio">
                <span>Portfolio</span>
            </a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </li>
```

What I need to try and do is

This is what it looks like now:

```
  <li class="   last-item SunItem-8"><a href="#><span>Blah</span></a></li>
```

But I need to have Jquery or javascript insert a few HTML elements before this, so it looks like:

```
  </li></ul><li><ul>
```

so it will look like this:

```
   </li></ul><li><ul><li class="   last-item SunItem-8"><a href="#><span>Blah</span></a></li>
```

Any help is appreciated, I have tried

```
          $(document).ready(function(){
           $("img").before("<ul><li><b>Before</b></li></ul>");
        });
```

But this does not seem to work, I have also tried this

```
  <script>
    (function() {
      var lastItem = $("li.SunItem-8");
      var currentList = lastItem.closest('ul');
      var newList = $("</ul></li><li><ul>");
      newList.insertAfter(currentList);
      newList.append(lastItem);
    })();
  </script>
```

This seem to duplicate the text and does not actually form the HTML tags as expected - the html output looks like this once inserting the above script.

```
  <li>
  <ul>
  <li class="   SunItem-5">
  <a href="http://gentex/website-packages/gold-package.aspx" title="Gold Package">
  <span>Gold Package</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li class="   SunItem-6">
  <a href="http://gentex/website-packages/platinum-package.aspx" title="Platinum Package">
  <span>Platinum Package</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li class="   SunItem-7">
  <a href="http://gentex/website-packages/cms-features.aspx" title="CMS Features">
  <span>CMS Features</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <li>
  <ul>
  </ul>
  <li class="   last-item SunItem-8">
  <a href="http://gentex/website-packages/portfolio.aspx" title="Portfolio">
  <span>Portfolio</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li class=" SunItem-8">
  <a href="http://gentex/website-packages/portfolio.aspx" title="Portfolio">
  <span>Portfolio</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li class="   last-item SunItem-8">
  <a href="http://gentex/website-packages/portfolio.aspx" title="Portfolio">
  <span>Portfolio</span>
  </a>
  </li>
  </li>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not working with html, you can not just insert tags. You will need to remove() the element and append a the new list with that element.

```
var lastItem = $("li.SunItem-8");
var parent = lastItem.parent();
lastItem.remove();
var newUL = $("<ul>").append(lastItem);
parent.after(newUL);
```

Comment: But this still seems to add duplicate entries x 3 as above.